# Generar palabras en array

Tags: javascript

Tengo los siguientes arrays:

```
var palabrasn1 = [
  ["foca", '/img/apple.png', "fruta", '/mp3/apple.mp3'],
  ["casa", '/img/apple.png', "hogar", '/mp3/apple.mp3'],
  ["momia", '/img/apple.png', "recipiente", '/mp3/apple.mp3'],
  ["vaso", '/img/apple.png', "personaje", '/mp3/apple.mp3']
  ];
```

Y mi funcion para elegir aleatoriamente una palabra del mismo:

```
  function generaPalabra() {
  rand = (Math.random() * 3).toFixed(0);
  if(nivel==1)palabra = palabrasn1[rand][0].toUpperCase();
  if(nivel==2)palabra = palabrasn2[rand][0].toUpperCase();
  if(nivel==3)palabra = palabrasn3[rand][0].toUpperCase();
  if(nivel==4)palabra = palabrasn4[rand][0].toUpperCase();
  if(nivel==5)palabra = palabrasn5[rand][0].toUpperCase();
  if(nivel==6)palabra = palabrasn6[rand][0].toUpperCase();
  console.log(palabra);
```

Pero cuando ejecuto hay veces que se repiten las palabras mas de 2 veces seguidas. Hay alguna manera de generar las palabras sin repetir? Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Creo que te podrías explicar un poco mejor sobre como exactamente quieres generar la palabra aleatoria, en lo que se puede ver en el código usas una variable `nivel` que no se explica para que la utilizas, tampoco la variable `palabra`.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza un 2 array que almacene los random que han ido apareciendo, utilitza indexOf para saber si el random esta dentro o no de la array almacenadora, si esta dentro no hagas nada, si no imprime palabra, una vez la array almacenadora de rnd mida igual que palabrasn1 detienes el bucle.

Comment: Bienvenido, te agradecemos tu respuesta, aunque queda deslucida sin código. En este enlace tienes el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos.